# How do we get users to ask good question on IT Security?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some outline help on asking questions is available on the [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq), but inexperienced users often ask poor questions. Is there any way to assist them in asking better questions?

Comment: This is covered in the FAQ.

Comment: @graham-lee True, a good deal is covered in the FAQ. Maybe the question should be how do we get users to ask good questions. My most recent modivation comes from [this question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5994/2737), where in a comment under my answer the OP gives critidcal details about the system purpose, users, and need for Creit Card numbers. The asker would get more specific and useful answers if that information was included in the question.

Answer (score 5):

> My most recent modivation comes from this question, where in a comment under my answer the OP gives critidcal details about the system purpose, users, and need for Creit Card numbers. The asker would get more specific and useful answers if that information was included in the question.

Specifically, then, enter a comment exhorting the OP to edit their post. If they do not edit it, edit it yourself.

There's a ton of help we display to new users on the https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask page -- including prominent links to the faq and short help blurbs on each entry area.

Carrot, meet stick.

I am open to hearing *specific suggestions* you may have on this, but if the OP is unwilling or unable to put in the effort, we can't *make* them do it. Garbage in, garbage out.. that's what downvotes and close votes are for.